# ReactJS return arrow without router

Tags: reactjs

```
class Overview extends React.Component {
    onMenuClick(id) {
        return this.props.onMenuClick(id);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ul className="categories">
                <li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "myOrder")}>My Order</li>
                <li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "technicalSupport")}>Technical Support</li>
                <li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "myPayments")}>My Payments</li>
                <li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "suggestions")}>Suggestions/ Questions</li>
            </ul>
        );
    } }


class MyOrder extends React.Component {

    onMenuClick(id) {
        return this.props.onMenuClick(id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-layout">
                <header>
                    <ul className="top">
                        <h1>Order & Delivery</h1>
                       ********<li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "overview")}>Back</li>********
                    </ul>
                </header>
                <ul className="categories">
                    <li>Where is my order?</li>
                    <li>My order delays more than the expected time</li>
                    <li>My order status shows that the order arrived but it did not</li>
                    <li>I have a complaint</li>
                    <li>Suggestions/ Questions</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

ReactJS beginner.
Trying to make the MyOrder li to be clickable like Overview li's. Why won't it work? I know it is not dynamic - I already know where will it go when pressing back arrow. Line with the ******** is the line I talk about. Also, how can I optimize my code?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there an error? What is not working? Can you produce a reproducible example?

Comment: ×
TypeError: this.props.onMenuClick is not a function
MyOrder.onMenuClick
C:/Users/OR/Desktop/ReactNative/HelpCenterReactJS/helpcenter/src/index.js:64
  61 | class MyOrder extends React.Component {
  62 | 
  63 |     onMenuClick(id) {
> 64 |         return this.props.onMenuClick(id);
  65 |     }
  66 | 
  67 |     render() {

Comment: Can you show the code that invokes `MyOrder` component? As the error says, it looks like your component doesn't have a onMenuClick props which is a function.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/X7Q51yZ4

Answer (score 0):

Well, given your pastebin, you do not assign the `onMenuClick` property to `MyOrder` component. So it can't call it afterwards. Add it like this, just like you do with `Overview`:

```
showComponent() {
    if(this.state.page === "overview") return (<Overview
        onMenuClick={this.switchPage.bind(this)}
    />);
    if(this.state.page === "myOrder") return (<MyOrder
        onMenuClick={this.switchPage.bind(this)}
    />);
    if(this.state.page === "technicalSupport") return <TechnicalSupport />;
    if(this.state.page === "myPayments") return <MyPayments />;
    if(this.state.page === "suggestions") return <Suggestions />;

    throw new Error(`${this.state.page} is not a valid page id`);
}
```

**About your code optimization**:

You might have realized that you copy/paste/repeat the same pieces of code a multiple times and always with the same set of values (your routes). I would create a configuration file, with an array of routes and its label, and then loop over it to display for each route the component.

If you do not want to do that, at least use a switch statement with only one render. See under:

```
showComponent() {
    const {
        page
    } = this.state;
    const Component = null;
    switch (page) {
        case 'overview':
            Component = Overview;
            break;
        case 'myOrder':
            Component = MyOrder;
            break;
        case 'technicalSupport':
            Component = TechnicalSupport;
            break;
        case 'myPayments':
            Component = MyPayments;
            break;
        case 'suggestions':
            Component = Suggestions;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error(`${page} is not a valid page id`);
            break;
    }

    return (
        <Component 
            onMenuClick={this.switchPage.bind(this)}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for responding. About the component - I only assigned the component for Main Panel, Overview does not have it and it works so why will it not work for MyOrder? About the config file could you please show me an example of how would you do that? Thank you so much.